# Android Studio desktop shortcut

Tags: 15.04, .desktop, android-studio

I made an android desktop file in ubuntu 15.04 as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Android Studio
Exec="/home/user/android-studio/bin/studio.sh" %f
Icon=/home/user/android-studio/bin/studio.png
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-android-studio
Name[en_GB]=android-studio.desktop
```

it shows the icon, and everything seems to be fine, but when i try to open it, does not open, with no  error message.
i have android studio version 1.3 preview

this is the output of `ls -la /home/user/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 6273 may 29 22:43 android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

Comment: Your desktop file is ok. [Edit] your question and add the output of `ls -la /home/user/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` and try to start Android Studio in a terminal with `/home/user/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` and post the output also in your question.

Comment: from terminal it starts normaly, i don't know why not from the .desktop

Comment: Only an idea, try this `Exec=/home/user/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` in the desktop file.

Comment: it does not work.

Comment: The desktop file is a little too big. Remove the file and create a new one with the lines posted in your question. My file has only 286. You have 6273.

Comment: now it has 269 and still does not start, thank you anyway.

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -la ~/.local/share/applications/android-studio.desktop `, assumed `android-studio.desktop` is your desktop file.

Comment: i have no desktop file for android studio in the location 
~/.local/share/applications/  , should it be there ?

Comment: Where is your desktop file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24293/discussion-between-a-b-and-rainman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place Android Studio in `/usr/share/applications` or any folder except your home user folder, you will need root privileges to execute the program.

In fact, if you try to execute in terminal `<folder where you installed Android Studio>/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`, you will be asked to enter root password. Yet, if you click on the icon of Android Studio nothing happens (nor password requests).

One way to avod this is to prompt a dialog box where to enter password.
Install **gksu** by typing in terminal `sudo apt-get install gksu`;
then edit your desktop file and in **Exec** entry write `gksu /<folder where you installed Android Studio>/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my android-studio.desktop file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/home/user/data/apps/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
Name=Android Studio
Comment=Android development powered by IntelliJ from Jetbrains
Icon=/home/user/data/apps/android-studio/bin/studio.png
Categories=Application;Development;
```

It's in ~/.local/share/applications/android-studio.desktop.

I installed Android Studio by downloading the zip and extracting it to 
~/data/apps/android-studio.

I can find Android Studio in Unity's application list. (An easier way to make a desktop file is to run the app and pin it to the Unity taskbar. I believe that creates one for you.)